# Expected Distance on $n \times n$ lattice

Tags: graph-theory

Take a lattice of size $n^2$ where $n$ is the length of each side. Now on these $n$ points randomly distribute five cops and one murderer. What is the expected distance from the nearest cop to the murderer (in terms of lattice points that is)?

Comment: On which $n$ points?

Comment: $n$ points arranged in a square with each cop/robber being able to move one square per move.

Comment: Is the distance in terms of moves, or is it the usual Euclidean distance?

Comment: Distance is the number of moves.

Comment: I still do not understand. The lattice has $(n+1)^2$ points, these guys occupy 6 points, and what are $n$ points?

Comment: [Also posted at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409360/randomly-distributed-pursuers-on-a-lattice).